# mutate data with linear equation

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a technical question for you please :

```
lonlon <- c(3.581667, 3.146667, 3.256667, 2.860000, 3.473333, 2.981667, 3.465000, 2.703333, 3.521667, 3.320000, 3.196667, 3.961667, 3.686667, 3.305000, 3.413333, 3.250000, 3.325000, 3.856667,  3.028333, 3.211667, 3.993333, 3.045000, 3.728333, 3.515000, 2.755000, 3.691667, 2.675000,  4.096667, 3.853333, 2.880000, 3.750000, 3.565000, 2.961667, 3.165000, 4.166667, 3.145000,  2.740000, 3.145000, 3.346667, 3.400000, 3.351667, 3.245000, 3.108333, 3.301667, 3.506667,  2.856667, 3.308333, 3.456667, 2.975000, 3.320000, 3.201667, 3.398333, 3.303333)

lala <- c(43.68167, 43.33667, 43.65333, 43.62000, 43.59500, 43.68333, 43.38833, 43.60167, 43.58167, 43.73833, 43.71167, 43.57667, 43.63500, 43.65500, 43.45667, 43.62167, 43.76333, 43.71667, 43.50167, 43.80000, 43.72833, 43.65500, 43.77833, 43.84167 ,43.48833, 43.39667 ,43.32667, 43.72000, 43.53667, 43.36333 ,43.94667, 43.32833 ,43.49000 ,43.27333 ,43.63333 ,43.47500, 43.41667, 43.64000, 43.70667, 43.43667 ,43.32167 ,43.78500 ,43.58333, 43.55000 ,43.66333, 43.38500, 43.86667, 43.79167, 43.66667, 43.49167 ,43.30167, 43.65500, 43.41167)

lulu <- c(round(runif(53), digits=5))
lulu <- paste("town_",lulu, sep = "") 
lili <- cbind.data.frame( lulu, lonlon, lala)

plot(lili$lonlon, lili$lala)
abline(b = 0.7, a = 41.25)
```

So, i want create 2 types of points. type 1 : points on the top/left and type 2 : points on the bottom/right. My linear equation is : y = 0.7x + 41.25.

In a precedent manipulation I used :

```
  lili2 <- lili %>% mutate(type= case_when(
  lonlon < 3.35 ~ 1,
  lonlon > 3.35 & lala < 43.59 ~ 2,
  lonlon > 3.35 & lala > 43.59 ~ 3
))
```

Is it possible to do the same manipulation but according to my diagonal (linear equation) please? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require(dplyr)

lili <- 
lili %>% 
  mutate(point_type  = if_else (lala >= (.7*lonlon + 41.25),1,2))
```

Comment: then consider clicking the check mark next to the answer.